# Updated build/Deployment of ECS docker images not reflecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

We have pushed our docker images (built on .net core) to AWS ECR repository. These docker images are pulled by AWS ECS (we updated task definitons, task service) and new tasks are created. The initial deployment process worked fine. But the following day after we pushed new updated docker images into the ECR repository, and created revisions of the task definitions and updated them on the service, our changes are not reflecting.
We deleted the ECR repository, ECS service and task definition and re-created all of these anew, but still the issue persists.

(we have killed the old tasks and new tasks have been started with the help of ECS service)

Requesting assistance on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine what's going on with this background. In general if you update your `task definition` with a new `revision` and make the new `revision` point to the new image `tag`, if you deploy the new revision you should see the changes included in the code that belongs to the image with the new `tag`. If you see the old code is because either the new `revision` point to an old `tag` and/or your new `revision` has the proper new `tag` but you are deploying an old `revision`.

If you are new to ECS perhaps a good way to setup all these plumbing would be to use [Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/). You don't have to use it to deploy to production (even though you can) but it could be a good learning exercise to explore how it sets up things. Basically it's a guided way to setup your ECS cluster as well as pipelines.

Comment: Hi @mreferre

 

Thanks for the revert. We have checked both the factors that you have suggested. We have observed and done both of these, but not sure how it is still reflecting the old data/changes. Also, to add on, we have another AWS account where the exact same setup is done. The same Docker image with same settings works perfectly fine there, with all changes reflecting fine.

Any suggestions/ areas to focus or check on?

Comment: Gosh this is really weird. One quick thing to check would be to point to the task currently showing the weird behavior and working backwards from it to make 100% sure it's running the image you intend it to be running. For example: focus on a task, check its task definition *and revision*, check what image tag the revision of said task definition is pointing to.

Comment: I also noted you are saying "data/changes". What is the nature of the "change" you expect? Is it data? Or is it code that is baked into the image? It's hard to debug this without knowing exactly how you built the containers, what you expect the container to have, not have, etc